# How to remove suggestions from WTForms

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I use Flask-Wtf forms to fill a date.
But I have problem with suggestions last chosen date. (screen below)
How to remove this suggestions.
My web browser is Google Chrome.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
{{ form.field_name(autocomplete="off") }}
```